# VB.NET upload file to a web url

Tags: vb.net, file-upload

i am writing a VB.Net app that has need to send a file to web script.

```
1. Dim uriString As New System.Uri("http://url/setup/image.php?title="+addNew_title.Text+"&price="+addNew_price.Text)
2. Dim myWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
3. Dim responseArray As Byte() = myWebClient.UploadFileAsync(uriString, OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
4. Dim response As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray)
```

There is a problem with URI that i give, it says "Expression does not produce a value" on line 3. where "uriString" used.

When i used myWebClient.UploadFile(String,String) it freeze on sending, so i found out, that to continue code execution i have to use "UploadFileAsync", but it does not provide [String,String], but it requires [Uri,String].

Just for the record, i will put a screenshot of code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZKIk.png

What do i have to change, so code is valid, or if there is another way to upload this file, please share :)

Comment: Unless the program is for personal or private use, I wouldn't recommend doing this through a VB .NET program. Since VB .NET is based on CLR, it is easy to decompile, to figure out how uploading is handled, and simulate that, just with malicious or larger files. You can encrypt your .NET code so that it can't be decompiled very easily through SmartAssembly. Oh, and, looking at your code, you don't have any form of authentication either. Just letting you know that it might be a good idea as a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

UploadFileAsync does not return any value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144232.aspx

You have to register an event handler to the [UploadFileCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfilecompleted.aspx) event to get the response or your request (that's actually the point of asynchronous method calls).

**Edit**

It is quite some time ago that I last programmed VB.Net, but I think the following should work as an example:

```
Public Class FileUploader

    Dim WithEvents client As New System.Net.WebClient()

    Public Sub StartUpload(ByVal targetUrl As String, ByVal filename As String)

        Dim uriString As New System.Uri(targetUrl)

        Me.client.UploadFileAsync(uriString, filename)

    End Sub

    Sub FileUploadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.UploadFileCompletedEventArgs) Handles client.UploadFileCompleted
        Dim response As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Result)

        ' further process your response string
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Could i ask an example code, for file sending, i have never sent files trought vb to http.